# Cannot upgrade PostgreSQL on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, apt

When I run `apt-get upgrade`, I get the following error :

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-9.1:
 postgresql-client-9.1 (9.1.7-0ubuntu12.04) breaks postgresql-9.1 (<< 9.1.7-0ubuntu12.04) and is installed.
  Version of postgresql-9.1 to be configured is 9.1.6-1~precise2.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-9.1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql:
 postgresql depends on postgresql-9.1; however:
  Package postgresql-9.1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing postgresql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                               No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-contrib-9.1:
 postgresql-contrib-9.1 depends on postgresql-9.1 (= 9.1.7-0ubuntu12.04); however:
  Version of postgresql-9.1 on system is 9.1.6-1~precise2.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-contrib-9.1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-contrib:
 postgresql-contrib depends on postgresql-contrib-9.1; however:
  Package postgresql-contrib-9.1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-contrib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-9.1
 postgresql
 postgresql-contrib-9.1
 postgresql-contrib
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried `apt-get -f upgrade` but the same error occurs.

What can I do to fix this issue? It totally messes up APT.

Note: I'm using the following PPA for PostgreSQL : https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql

Update: Sorry for the formatting, here is a gist https://gist.github.com/e0752bb50e63ef4b3a4c

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. `apt-get -f install` doesn't worked. With aptitude it worked.

`aptitude -f install` removed postgres but not the databases. Afterwards `apt-get install postgres` reinstalled postgres. Happy again :-)

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem on a test machine some time ago.
I just disabled the pitti, uninstalled, cleaned, reinstalled, enabled pitti, updated.
Maybe I am missing some steps but for me it helped.
Relevant lines from *history*:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntugis-ppa-precise.list
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pitti-postgresql-precise.list
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.1
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-client-9.1
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis 
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.1 
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pitti-postgresql-precise.list
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntugis-ppa-precise.list 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: BTW you could probably `sudo su -` once and then run all the commands without having to prefix them all with sudo!

Comment: I am aware of that possibility and use it where appropriate, but I usually use sudo because of nice lines in /var/log/auth.log (logs user and command). Additionally I like to work on user privileges, and gain elevated privileges specifically for one line.

Comment: Does the uninstall clean the existing databases or are they kept?

Comment: When I run apt-get remove postgresql-9.1, the same error message appears...

Comment: @OyoKooN: I wonder the same. 99% sure I would say NO. 'apt-get purge' would delete it. 'apt-get remove' not. But 99% is not enough for a production DB ;-)